# Identifying dense magnetic rock with tubular features

Tags: rocks, meteorite, rock-magnetism

I recently found a few rocks scattered in a valley, without any clues about where they may have come from (they did not look anything like the local soil, rocks, or layers of rock that could be seen in the surroundings).

The rocks seem ferromagnetic (magnets are attracted to them) and have a high density (It feels similar to other metals, but I don't have good tools to measure mass/volume at the moment).

I tested magnetism with a needle suspended on a string, and they may produce a weak magnetic field, but it's hard to tell.

The other interesting characteristic are tube-like formations as seen in these pictures:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any ideas about what it could be?

Answer (score 4):

The items look like [slag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slag), the dumped wasted product of metal smelting. The high density suggests a high metal content. The magnetic properties suggests a significant iron content and the smooth curved surfaces and internal bubbles suggests solidification from a molten material. A smooth surface or a glassy appears indicates rapid cooling.

Comment: That would be surprising as it is in a remote rural area hundreds of km from any industrial facility (and 15km from any village).  Could that melting pattern be that of a meteorite?  What further tests would help clarify the question?

Comment: it is not a meteorite that is for sure.the lack of other alternatives makes me sure that it must be slag,burnt and expanded clay might look simmilar to your sample but it is not magnetic so it canot be burnt clay.